# The convolution of two functions is L1

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution

I have to proof the following corollary:

> $ \text{Let } 1 \leq p \leq \infty \text{, } f \in L^{1} \text{, } g\in L^{p} \text{. Then } f \ast g \in L^p \text{ and } \Vert f \ast g \Vert _{L^{p}} \leq  \Vert f \Vert _{L^{1}} \Vert g \Vert _{L^{p}}$.

I understood the proof for the case $p < \infty$, and in my lecture notes it is only written "for the case $p = \infty$ the result follows directly from Hölder's inequality. 
Now my problem is: the Hölder's inequality yields a result for $fg$, not for $f \ast g$, so I don't really see the link.

Thank you!

Comment: if $f, g \ge 0$ then $\|f \ast g\|_{L^1} = \int_X \int_X f(x) g(y-x) dx dy =\int_X \int_X f(x) g(y-x) dy dx = \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^1}$

Comment: I think it's supposed to be $||f\ast g||_p\leq ||f||_1||g||_p$. This is called Young's inequality.

Comment: Yes carmichael561, you're right, I meant $||f\ast g||_p\leq ||f||_1||g||_p$. How do I prove it for $p=\infty$?

Answer (score 5):

If $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^{\infty}$, then
$$ |(f\ast g)(x)|=\Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)g(y)\;dy\Big|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x-y)g(y)|\;dy\leq ||g||_{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(y)|\;dy=||f||_1||g||_{\infty}$$
using the translation-invariance of Lebesgue measure. Therefore $||f\ast g||_{\infty}\leq ||f||_1||g||_{\infty}$.

Comment: Okay! Is there any way to prove it using Holder's inequality instead of this?

Comment: Well the second inequality is basically Holder's inequality for the $(1,\infty)$ case.

Comment: But doesn't Holder state: $ f \in L^{1} \text{, } g\in L^{\infty} \implies fg \in L^\infty \text{ and } \Vert fg \Vert _{L^{\infty}} \leq  \Vert f \Vert _{L^{1}} \Vert g \Vert _{L^{\infty}}$ ? It has no convolution in it...

Comment: The second inequality in my proof is Holder's inequality applied to the functions $y\mapsto f(x-y)$ and $y\mapsto g(y)$, together with an omitted step that used the translation invariance of the integral.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's clear now!

Answer (score 1):

By Hölder's inequality, you get
$$
|f\ast g(x)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} |f(y)g(x-y)|\;{\rm d}y = \|f g(x-\cdot)\|_1\leq \|g\|_\infty \|f\|_1
$$
since $|g(x-y)|\leq \|g\|_\infty$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ since $\|g(x-\cdot)\|_\infty=\|g\|_\infty$.
This implies
$$
\|f\ast g\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_\infty
$$

Comment: But doesn't Holder state: $ f \in L^{1} \text{, } g\in L^{\infty} \implies fg \in L^\infty \text{ and } \Vert fg \Vert _{L^{\infty}} \leq  \Vert f \Vert _{L^{1}} \Vert g \Vert _{L^{\infty}}$ ? It has no convolution in it...

Comment: @nbayo: No, it says $\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_\infty$ and here it is applied to the shifted version of $g$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's clear now! I didn't think, that I should apply it to the shifted version.